# "Scheduler already exists issue" persists

Tags: c#, quartz.net, job-scheduling

Even though I have used *Tarun Arora*'s [solution](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2013/01/19/quartz.net-windows-service-on-server-important-configuration-steps-to-remember.aspx) to the

> Scheduler with the name xxx already exists.

issue, I still get the same error. This is his solution and I assume he has already implemented the *Singleton* pattern correctly:

```
public class Scheduler
{
    public readonly IScheduler Instance;
    public string Address { get; private set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobGroup { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string CronExpression { get; set; }

    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;


    public Scheduler(string server, int port, string scheduler)
    {
        Address = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", server, port, scheduler);
        _schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(GetProperties(Address));

        try
        {
            Instance = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

            if (!Instance.IsStarted)
                Instance.Start();
        }
        catch (SchedulerException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }

    private static NameValueCollection GetProperties(string address) 
    {
        var properties = new NameValueCollection();
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "ServerScheduler";
        properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "0";
        properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = address;
        return properties;
    }

    public IScheduler GetScheduler()
    {
        return Instance;
    }
}
```

I must confess I am not using the last part in which he says

> If you wanted to call Scheduler then you should be using something
>   like the code sample below…

```
public SchedulerMetaData GetMetaData()
{
        var scheduler = new Scheduler("ServerName", Convert.ToInt32("PortNumber"), "Scheduler"));
        return scheduler.GetMetaData();
}
```

This how I am calling the scheduler in my application:

```
IScheduler sched = new Scheduler(logger, "127.0.0.1", 555, "QuartzScheduler").Instance;
IJobDetail postbagjob = null;
ITrigger postbagJobTrigger = null;
try
{
    postbagjob = JobBuilder.Create<PostbagJob>()
        .WithIdentity(jobName, jobGroup)
        .UsingJobData("CampaignId", campaignId.ToString())
        .UsingJobData("CampaignType", campaignType)
        .Build();
    postbagJobTrigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity(triggerName, triggerGroup)
        .WithCronSchedule(cron)
        .StartAt(DateTime.Now)
        .Build();
}
catch (SchedulerException ex)
{
    MsgBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

It works the first time I am about to add the job, but the second time I call it, `sched` becomes `null`.

Comment: is it going out of scope and being garbage collected. are you assigning null to it by mistake? sounds like a job for the debugger.

Comment: Where are you calling the last bit of code? `IScheduler sched` must be singleton.

Comment: @LeftyX they are all on the same project, the last bit of code is calling the scheduler class.

Comment: @Pedram: yes, I got that. If you're calling that code inside a EX: button click `sched` is not going to be singleton but it will run out of scope.

Comment: @LeftyX true. the scheduler is instantiated after the click of a button. So what do you suggest I do to keep it singleton?

Comment: @Pedram: You can use a static member or singleton pattern => [article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static)

Comment: @LeftyX but the above solution already claims that it is using a singleton pattern. But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested that implementation and it seems to work.
There must be something else in your solution which prevents things from working properly.

Are you sure that the job which is running in your server is the `PostbagJob` ?

I would advise you to check the configuration of your server. Make sure that you have something like this:

```
<add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz"/>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.port" value="555"/>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName" value="QuartzScheduler"/>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType" value="tcp"/>
<add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName" value="httpQuartz"/>
```

What can you tell us about your **cron** trigger? Can you post the cron expression?
Why don't you try to change it to a simple trigger and see how it works:

```
postbagJobTrigger = (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("SampleTrigger", "QUARTZGROUP")
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(2).RepeatForever())
        .StartNow()
        .Build();
```

Another thing that you should do is share an assembly with jobs between server and client so that they have the same signature.

I made a few changes to the `Scheduler` class. You can find the end result [here](https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzServer).

**NOTE:**

To run the server and the client, make sure you have **multiple startup projects** configured in your solution (right click on solution).

**UPDATE:**

A better approach is to create a singleton class this way:

```
public sealed class QuartzScheduler
{
    private static QuartzScheduler instance = null;

    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    private readonly ISchedulerFactory SchedulerFactory = null;
    private readonly IScheduler Scheduler = null;

    QuartzScheduler()
    {
        this.SchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        this.Scheduler = this.SchedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    }

    public static IScheduler Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new QuartzScheduler();
                }
                return instance.Scheduler;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to [read](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) more you can find lot of useful info on Jon Skeet's blog.
*NB: I've used the third version.*

Now you can simply use that object in your windows forms application:

```
QuartzScheduler.Instance.ScheduleJob(postbagjob, postbagJobTrigger);
```

No more than that.

If you check my **github** [repo](https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzServer) you can find a working solution.
I've moved the client configuration in the `app.config` file; I guess it's easier to customize:

```
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.ZeroSizeThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="RemoteClient"/>
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="0"/>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.proxy" value="true"/>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.proxy.address" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:555/QuartzScheduler"/>
</quartz>
```

Another thing to remember is your client is scheduling jobs, not really running the scheduler, so you should configure your thread pool as `ZeroSizeThreadPool`.

Comment: But my error happens before creating any jobs. I have an "Add Scheduler" button on my form. And this error happens in the `Scheduler` class on line `Instance = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();` because once the scheduler is bound, it does not want you to create a new StdScheduleFactory for it. So I am looking for a way to let my program now that once we defined one factory, do not do it for the second time. But Singleton patterns I find are to no help.

Comment: When I press the button for the second time, this `SchedulerException`is thrown. If there was a way to know the Schedulers contained in the Factory, then we can prevent this somehow. It is strange that it is working in your case. But you told me that I should not do this in a button click event. Do you think it's better to create this instance when my main form loads or something similar?

Comment: @Pedram I would create the scheduler when the application starts and also make it a singleton

Comment: @CircularReference so you agree that the above code is not making it a singleton? I will try to move the scheduler to my application start and see if it works.

Comment: [see this](https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzServer/blob/master/Quartz.ClientScheduler/Form1.cs#L16)

Comment: @LeftyX you are right. The Scheduler class must be instantiated once and at the beginning of the program. If you instantiate it twice it will throw that `SchedulerException`. Now I got it working. I just don't understand what the point of the singleton pattern is if the class actually allows you to create a second instance of it? I mean the point in singleton is that it should return the current instance, not to throw an exception and crash your program. You can post your answer so I select as the correct choice anyway. Thank you so much again.

Comment: @Pedram: I've updated my answer with some more info about the singleton pattern. My github repo has got the whole implementation. Read the last bit of my answer cause there are few other things you have to remember when running client/server with Quartz.Net.

Answer (score 0):

For the Quartz web service, restarting the app pool fixed this issue.